# Jaxb/MOXY ClassExtractor on XmlElement

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I'm facing an issue using jaxb, when unmarshalling my xml, I can't manage to make the difference between one of my classes and an inherited one.

I got a 1 st class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlClassExtractor(PersonExtractor.class)
@XmlSeeAlso(Toto.class)
public class Person {
}
```

An inherited one:

```
public class Toto
extends Person
{
    @XmlElement(name = "additionalInformation")
    private String additionalInformation;
}
```

My extractor:

```
public class PersonExtractor
extends ClassExtractor
{
@Override
public Class extractClassFromRow(Record pArg0, Session pArg1)
{
    if (pArg0.get("additionalInformation") != null || pArg0.get("@additionalInformation") != null)
    {
        return Toto.class;
    }
    else
    {
        return Person.class;
    }
}
```

}

Unfortunately this doesn't works.
When I'm trying to unmarshall Person.class is always returned.
If I change:
@XmlElement(name = "additionalInformation")
into
@XmlAttribute(name = "additionalInformation")
Everything works fine (unfortunately I do want an element).

None of those classes is my root element (everything is "deep" into my model)
Does someone know what I am missing ? probably somthing really dumb, but can't manage to put my hand on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a namespace define for your root element (or default namespace), so the element name is not additionalInformation but namespace:additionalInformation (or however it is represented in the Record element). Have you also checked that content of Toto class is saved correctly witht he additionalInformation element (I guess it was since it works with attribute, but just in case).

You can printout the content of your Record element to see what and how is stored there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, I found a solution:

Apparently currently MOXy requires that the inheritance indicator is in an XML attribute for the @XmlClassExtractor to work.
I ended up finding and using an other way to handle inheritance using @XmlAdapter